# difference between r-squared and adjusted r -squared , can somebody help me in finding the good source for the same?

Tags: machine-learning, statistics

I have gone through some videos on regression algorithm like linear, polynomial, decision trees, random forest. but when it came to explaining about R-squared and adjusted R- squared , i could not understand the topic very well when it explains how adding more variable can affect our model.

I searched through various online sources but trying to find the simplest explanation for the same and how these two help us decide making our model more robust

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not really a pandas or python question, but more of a statistics question.  Regardless - here's a short explanation.

r-squared refers to the 'goodness' of fit for a particular model with no regard for the number of independent variables.  Whereas, adjusted r-squared takes into account the number of independent variables.

So if you have a regression equation such as

```
y = mx + nx1 + ox2 + b
```

The r-squared will tell you how well that equation describes your data.  If you add more independent variables (p, q, r, s ...) then the r-square value will improve because you are in essence more specifically defining your sample data.  (Careful, this could lead to overfitting - aka you can perfectly describe the training data but not properly predict new data).  Using adjusted R-squared metric instead takes into account that you have added more independent variables and will 'penalize' the result for the more variables you add which don't fit the sample data.  This is a good way to test the variables, either by adding in one at a time and checking when the adj-R2 starts to deteriorate or by starting with all the variables and removing one at a time until the adj-R2 doesn't improve.

Here's an [explanation](https://www.statisticshowto.datasciencecentral.com/adjusted-r2/) of the statistical description of these two metrics.

Comment: Thanks Michael, yeah i should have tagged it correctly but I included the other tags because It was related topic during my research of the subject. but thanks for your answer with the link.